# Swift Assign Button Position from Plist

Tags: swift, ios8

I have Add Constraint in My func

```
func CreateButtonWithIndex(var index:Int) {

    let path = loadPath()
    var data = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    let newButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton       newButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    self.view.addSubview(newButton)

   let newButtonConstraintL = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newButton, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50)

    let newButtonConstraintH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newButton, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50)

 //   Read from Plist the coordinate

    var reloadCoordX:[String] = data!.valueForKey("\(strDaPassare) X") as[String]
    var reloadCoordY:[String] = data!.valueForKey("\(strDaPassare) Y") as[String]
    var coordX: Int = ("\(reloadCoordX[index-1])").toInt()!
    var coordY: Int = ("\(reloadCoordY[index-1])").toInt()!

    // Add Constraint

    newButtonConstraintX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newButton, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(coordX))

    newButtonConstraintY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newButton, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(coordY))
```

}

And it's ok !!!! but this takes as a reference center of the UIView it self for the values ​​of newButtonConstraintX and newButtonConstraintY . but if I want to set attribute for newButtonConstraintX and newButtonConstraintY for the Top left corner ?

Comment: Why the `CGFloat("\(point.x)")`? Have you tried using `point.x`? Same for y.

Comment: yes excuse me i have edit my question

Comment: Can you println `point`? Maybe the conversion from the `buttonPosition` fails and (0,0) is returned?

Comment: println(point)  // (-200.0,-90.0)(-120.0,-140.0)(-200.0,-40.0) for tree

Comment: how can I Increase the value of a position buttonPosition ?